# Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: notes(com.muradsapplications.quicknote.model.Notes). (Kotlin)

Tags: database, kotlin, android-room

My Error is :

```
TableInfo{name='notes', columns={dateTime=Column{name='dateTime', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, color=Column{name='color', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, imagePath=Column{name='imagePath', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, webLink=Column{name='webLink', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, subtitle=Column{name='subtitle', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='notes', columns={id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, Title=Column{name='Title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, dateTime=Column{name='dateTime', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, subtitle=Column{name='subtitle', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, noteText=Column{name='noteText', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, imagePath=Column{name='imagePath', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, color=Column{name='color', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, webLink=Column{name='webLink', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

Database Image :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VykMI.png

Here is my Entity :

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes")
data class Notes(
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
 @ColumnInfo(name = "id") @NotNull var id : Int,
 @ColumnInfo(name = "title")  @NotNull var title : String,
 @ColumnInfo(name = "dateTime") @NotNull var dateTime : String,
 @ColumnInfo(name = "subtitle") @NotNull var subtitle : String,
 @ColumnInfo(name = "imagePath") @NotNull var imagePath : String,
 @ColumnInfo(name = "color")  @NotNull var color : String,
 @ColumnInfo(name = "webLink") @NotNull var webLink : String

)  : java.io.Serializable{
}
```

my Dao provider with Hilt

```
  @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideNoteDao(@ApplicationContext context: Context) : NotesDao{
        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(context,MyDatabase::class.java,"notes.sqlite")
            .createFromAsset("notes.sqlite").build()
        return db.getNotesDao()
    }
}
```

I was trying to access my local database made with ROOM. But i face with Error.(KOTLIN)

Answer (score 0):

Typically it is unlikely that you can just take a database not created via Room and just use it via Room.

When you code an @Entity annotated class and include that class in the list of entities in the @Database annotated class. Room determines the columns and their types. Room **Expects** an exact match between that and the database that it opens. i.e. what Room **Found**. If they do not match then you get the error that shows what Room expects and what it found and there will be a discrepancy between the two, albeit difficult to detect what the mismatch is.

There is no real need to try to ascertain what the difference is. In short the database when opened MUST be as Room expects. Room kindly generates the SQL for what room expects and this can then be used as the basis for converting the source database.

The conversion can either be done outside of room and the converted database can then be the pre-packaged database. Or the `prepackagedDatabaseCallback` method.

In either case the conversion will in many situations be along the lines of:-

1. rename the source database e.g. `ALTER TABLE RENAME original TO old_original;`
2. COPY THE SQL that Room generated that will create the table according to Room's expectations
3. Populate  the new table from the old table e.g. `INSERT INTO original SELECT * FROM old_original;`
4. Delete the pre convertered renamed table e.g. `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS old_original;`

- **original** represents the name of the table that will be used (notes in your case)
- **Note** see the **Additional** section below, as it appears that the prepackaged database you have provided may not be the prepackaged
  database you expected to provide. i.e. the image you supplied of the provided database does not match the actual database that was provided.

The all important SQL that is generated by room can be found by:-

1. Using the Android View
2. Locating the java (generated) folder/directory that is displayed in the Android View
3. Locating the class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class but suffixed with **Impl**.
4. Locating the method **createAllTables**

There will be a `CREATE ....` SQL statement for each table that room expects. There will also be two statements for the room_master_table, one to create it and another to insert the single row. There is no need to create the room_master_table nor to insert the row, Room manages the table and should be left to do so.

**Additional**

After editing your question and changing the log to appear as code, then it is obvious that discrepancies exist, as the length of each differs and it is apparent that there are more columns in the source/original table than those defined via the Entity. Room will NOT accept this.

Looking into the matter then

- there are 8 columns in the source database only 7 in the Entity. The **noteText** column has been omitted from the Entity.
- the **title**, **subtitle**, **imagepath**, **color** and **webLink** columns in the source do not have the NOT NULL constraint.

To ascertain the above the expected/found part of the log was dropped into a test editor, split at each column and the columns from the found and the expected copied to their own lines each above the respective other.

e.g. :-

```
TableInfo{name='notes', 
    columns={
        dateTime=Column{name='dateTime', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
        color=Column{name='color', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
        imagePath=Column{name='imagePath', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
        webLink=Column{name='webLink', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
        subtitle=Column{name='subtitle', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
        id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
        title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}
    }, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
TableInfo{name='notes', 
    columns={
        id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
        Title=Column{name='Title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
        dateTime=Column{name='dateTime', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
        subtitle=Column{name='subtitle', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
        noteText=Column{name='noteText', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
        imagePath=Column{name='imagePath', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
        color=Column{name='color', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
        webLink=Column{name='webLink', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}
    }, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
    
    
    id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, F
    id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, E
    
    Title=Column{name='Title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, F
    title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'} E
    
    dateTime=Column{name='dateTime', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, F
    dateTime=Column{name='dateTime', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, E
    
    subtitle=Column{name='subtitle', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, F
    subtitle=Column{name='subtitle', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, E
    
    noteText=Column{name='noteText', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, F
    ???? E
    
    imagePath=Column{name='imagePath', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, F
    imagePath=Column{name='imagePath', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, E
    
    color=Column{name='color', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, F
    color=Column{name='color', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, E
    
    webLink=Column{name='webLink', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, F
    webLink=Column{name='webLink', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, E
```

**As such the strategy above would need to be changed accordingly**.

It may simply be that the source database used is not in fact the intended source database. It certainly does not match the database described in the image.

Otherwise you will need to:-

1. determine whether or not the notetext column is required, if not then the `INSERT INTO original SELECT * FROM old_original` will have to change so that instead of `SELECT  *` the specific required columns are specified.
2. for the columns that do not have the NOT NULL constraint, then a null value must be converted to a non null value (e.g. using coalesce function).